# WebDAV request for file inside virtual directory

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, webdav, virtual-directory, filetable

I'm storing files in SQL Server 2012 using a `FileTable`. Someone logged onto the server can access the files via a virtual directory which SQL Server set up (`\\hostname\sqlexpress\FileTableTestFilestreamDirectoryName\FileTableTestFilestream\`). I'd like to enable an authenticated user of my web app to download/open a file inside this directory for editing, using the WebDAV protocol.

**NOTE:** I'm not talking about the IIS Virtual Directory; this is a "special" virtual directory that SQL Server 2012 created in order for users to add/edit/delete files directly from within Windows (while SQL Server continues monitoring the files in the directory).

I'd like to be able to handle the browser's `GET` request for a file like this:

```
https://example.com/virtual_directory_path/Filename.docx
```

This would enable the web app user to open/edit the file and save it back to the same directory. I know there are security considerations here which I will have to address at some point, but for just proof-of-concept, can I do this?

Just to confirm: If I enter:

```
\\hostname\sqlexpress\FileTableTestFilestreamDirectoryName\FileTableTestFilestream\Filename.docx
```

into my browser, I get the correct file returned to my browser, and I use my desktop app (Word) to edit and save it back to the original location. And since SQL Server monitors the files in the virtual directory, it detects the file updates I make.

Is there a way to pass a request in a url directly to the file I want (as above), get that file returned, make changes and Save, and have those changes reflected inside the virtual file directory? You know, SharePoint like, but using WebDAV instead.

Comment: Please add your tried codes, But I think you need to change your way of entering a URL then accessing the file to something like using `QueryString` ;).

Comment: My tried codes [sic] are in my original post. But my question isn't really about the code; it's the uri and/or protocol.